# How to make rsync actually continue from where it left off?

Tags: linux, rsync

As a total newbie, after reading tons of questions in SO and the documentation repetitively several times, I came up with this solution:

```
rsync -Pavuh --append-verify source destination
```

Where `--append-verify` flag implies `--inplace` flag and `--inplace` flag implies `--partial` and I only put the `-P` flag there because I am lazy to write `--progress` separately.

Yet, when I issue this command, and `Ctrl+C` it in the middle of a big file, and then re-issue it, after it finishes I see that that big file is left where I cut it off.

The right behaviour should be as per documentation to leave the partially transferred file as-is on cancellation according to the `--partial` flag (which is done) and then continue to append to it on the second trial according to the `--append-verify` flag.

How can I make rsync resume from where it was interrupted?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is probably the `-u` flag. Since the partially transferred file has a newer timestamp it just skips it.

In theory, the `-t` option should ensure that this does not happen, but my hypothesis is that some (all?) kinds of interruption can leave the partial file with a newer datestamp. I've not tested this.

I don't see any other option there that has any variation on the "skip some files" theme, so it's my best guess.

Comment: From the documentation: _--update: This forces rsync to skip any files which exist on the destination and have a modified time that is newer than the source file. (If an existing destination file has a modification time equal to the source file's, it will be updated if the sizes are different.)_  So, it should check the file sizes.

Comment: @duru See edit.